# mysql redundancy with mixed storage types

Tags: mysql, cluster, high-availability, redundancy

Looking at building redundancy into our system, as we are currently, um, exposed should anything blow up.

We have a large-ish DB (150G), consisting of a mix of innoDB and myISAM table types. We want to build redundancy in, with a pair of DB servers, with silent failover should one go down. Clustering looked good, but docs imply new NDB table type, and I don't want to have to change anything.

MySQLProxy looks a bit, well, new and fragile (am I mistaken?) and we need this to be stable, high availability DB.

Which way should we go ? (speccing server purchase at the moment, so early days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last I checked mysql proxy was still a beta :-). What about master-master replication where the servers share the same IP using either CARP or Heartbeat? 
And if needed, you can have a third pure slave for read-only queries too!
I haven't used this in production, but I know it's not that uncommon with problems when running master-master, so I think one would prevent most of the problems if running shared virtual IP.

Comment: Looks good, many thanks. 3 Techs now reading up on heartbeat and DRBD.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [mmm](http://mysql-mmm.org/) also. I'm studying it now to use on production.